# How can I make my Python NLTK pre-processing code more efficient?

Tags: python, text, nltk

I am trying to import Yelp reviews and pre-process the text data using Python so I can find most frequently used nouns in the reviews and in turn extract informative aspects. I have come up with the following code and wanted someone to let me know if there is more efficient way to writing this code for the purpose:

```html
    import pandas as pd
    import nltk
    import os

    # Import data files
    path='~\Revsfile'
    filename='blrevs.csv'

    os.chdir(path)
    df1=pd.read_csv(filename, encoding="utf-8") # Set encoding to assist with sent_tokenize command later on
    df2=df1[['id','brand','Rating','Description']] # Description includes the review text

    # Remove missing characters
    df2['Description']=df2['Description'].fillna('')

    # Preprocess text data and tokenize words
import string
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re

stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))

def preprocess(sentence):
 sentence = sentence.lower()
 tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
 tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)
 filtered_words = [w for w in tokens if not w in stops]
 return " ".join(filtered_words)

df2['tokenized_words']=df2['Description'].apply(preprocess)
```

Comment: While the code is processing correctly, I am getting the following message after running this code. Could there be an issue? "SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy".

Answer (score 1):

The message you see comes up all too often when you work with a dataframe. It means pandas is not sure your operation is safe, but it is not sure that it *is* a problem, either. Figure out a work-around to be safe, but that's not the source of your performance problem.

I didn't profile your code, but your `clean_up()` function in particular is horrible. Why do you keep splitting, processing and re-joining? Tokenize once, filter the tokens, then join the final result if you must.

In addition to the redundant splitting-joining, you do it inefficiently by needlessly building a temporary array that you pass to `join()`. Use a generator instead (i.e., leave out the square brackets) and your performance should improve dramatically. For example, instead of `''.join([singularize(plural) for plural in s])` you can write:

```
s = ''.join(singularize(plural) for plural in s)
```

I can't go into more detail because to be frank, your tokenization is a mess. When and how will you apply `sent_tokenize()`, after you've removed the punctuation? Also the line I rewrote above is (and was) trying to "singularize" indidivual letters, if I'm not mistaken. Think more carefully about what you're doing, work with tokens as I recommended (consider using `nltk.word_tokenize()`-- but it's not as fast as a single `split()`), and inspect the intermediate steps.

Comment: Appreciate your candid feedback. I have updated my code based on your guidance and hope that this is a better approach to preprocessing text data.